# Burn Bootstrapper Project Using Radiobuttons on a the Options page

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

Is it possible to use a radio button on an overridden rtftheme.xml form for a boostrapper wix setup project. I want to present the use with two mutually exclusive options.

I have managed to do this with checkboxes but these are not mutually exclusive

Kind Regards

Scott

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Button` with `HexStyle="0x000009"`.